# Is raspberry able to retrieve/store some n time prior a trigger with multiple cameras?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3b+, picamera, framebuffer

I came across a project idea which I think would demand a lot from a raspberry pi and arduino hardware capabilities. From my understanding, a master raspberry could be used to trigger n slaves through GPIO pins for multiple camera usage, but I am not sure how to accomplish what I want from that. I might be wrong but I was thinking that there might be a camera/image sensor which could store video for the last n seconds and when needed, the controller would retrieve that data. For example, if my lightbulb get burnt I can see the exact moment that it happened if I retrieve the last couple of minutes (and if it is within the timeframe obviously).

If this is possible, I could just set the timeframe I would like to cover prior to a trigger, perhaps always recording the desired timeframe until needed.

But if this is not possible at all, I can just think of the controller having an array or cluster of frames equal to the needed time, but this will demand a lot from the hardware and I would like different angles(multiple cameras).

I've seen people using multiple V2 cameras for 3D purposes, but I am not sure if the requirement of storing that amount of data is possible with these.

Any tip or advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: `there might be a camera/image sensor which could store video for the last n seconds` ... yes, a dashcam